# WPF, c#, reference a specific UI element by its name

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, user-interface

I have an application and I need to switch between multiple menus. My method for doing this is (as I've done before in Unity) is group all the elements of each menu into a Canvas GUI element, and using code to set which ones are visible and which are not. I'm just not sure how to reference the canvas itself in code (or the others, since I need multiple ones but I'm starting with one for now) in Visual Studio.

The only 'solution' I found (throws an error):

`object mainCanvas = Canvas.Findname("Main_Menu");`

Comment: Have you tried ref-ing it simply by the name without trying to find it? For example, for `<Canvas Name="mainCanvas"/>` do `var currentCanvas = mainCanvas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a XAML based UI, the way to do this is to assign a name to the Canvas, and then it is accessible in the code-behind.

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"/>
```

Then in the code behind

```
void SomeEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myCanvas...//Do whatever you were going to do with the canvas.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's just the info I was looking for!

Comment: To I guess clarify this answer for others:

A UI element in WPF/XAML has many properties, but some are not put into the editor by default. If you add `Name="myName"` in that set of properties, that gives a 'name' to the UI element. You can then just reference that name in the code like its any other declared object, though the exact commands it works with vary based on the UI element.